# How do I get traceroute to work like tcptraceroute?

Tags: networking, tcp, traceroute

On Mac OS 11 the man page for traceroute says you can set it to TCP mode with `-P TCP`. When I attempt to do this I get no responses:

```
[me@laptop ~]$ sudo traceroute -f 6 -m 10 -e -P TCP -p 443 www.serverfault.com
traceroute: Warning: www.serverfault.com has multiple addresses; using 151.101.129.69
traceroute to serverfault.com (151.101.129.69), 10 hops max, 64 byte packets
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
```

When I use tcptraceroute I get results:

```
[me@laptop ~]$ sudo tcptraceroute -f 6  www.serverfault.com 443
Selected device en15, address 192.168.1.100, port 61967 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to www.serverfault.com (151.101.129.69) on TCP port 443 (https), 30 hops max
 6  be2073.ccr31.jfk10.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.0.230)  20.935 ms  20.801 ms  21.431 ms
 7  38.122.228.2  20.261 ms  20.135 ms  19.685 ms
 8  151.101.129.69 [open]  27.103 ms  27.327 ms  27.026 ms
```

I've used wireshark to verify that traceroute is sending TCP SYNs and getting ICMP TTL Exceeded responses. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

The traceroute version in newer versions of MacOS even Ventura is not broken, it's just an older version.  Apple has not kept up with latest versions found in newer Linux distributions.  The behavior you are seeing is that the port option only sets the base port.

Quoted from [man pages](https://ss64.com/osx/traceroute.html):

```
-p port
```

> Protocol specific. For UDP and TCP, sets the base port number used in probes (default is 33434).  traceroute hopes that nothing is
> listening on UDP ports base to base+nhops-1 at the destination host (so an ICMP PORT_UNREACHABLE message will be returned to
> terminate the route tracing).  If something is listening on a port in the default range, this option can be used to pick an unused
> port range.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by base port. I understand that the udp mode increments port numbers, but I can see with Wireshark that when running my command above, all my SYN packets have a destination port of 443.

Answer (score -1):

TCP traceroute is heavily broken on MAC even in Ventura.

Look at your wireshark output - instead of sending TCP SYN packets to specified port (e.g. 80) it increments port number for every attempt.

So TCP SYNs go to port 81,82,83, etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see the behavior that you're describing. All my SYN packet are going to the port I specified on the command line. What you're describing sounds like the expected behavior for traceroute in the default UDP mode.